# Are "Imperial Eastman" compression connections sized the same as regular imperial connections?

Tags: pressure, compressed-air, vacuum, tools

I have some high pressure and vacuum lines off of a tool from the 1980s and they are labeled as, for example, "3/8 imperial - eastman," which seems to be different from how normal compression connections are labeled.

Is this the same as regular imperial units, or is there some difference I need to be aware of? Where can I find these parts?

Comment: A photo of the connections would go a long ways towards identifying them and their potential compatibility with other connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Imperial Eastman" is the name of the now-defunct company that originally manufactured the tool. It exists today as [the Imperial Tools brand of Stride Tool](http://imperial-tools.com/about-us). The part you mention is probably just a standard 3/8" fitting or hose but if you're concerned about it, you could take a look at their [replacement parts guides](http://imperial-tools.com/support/replacement-parts).

If you want to get the parts elsewhere and you're worried about compatibility, you should be able to get equivalent parts from any large supplier. If you can find the actual part number on the fitting (not just the nominal dimension), you may be able to find the equivalent part in a document like [this Equivalent Products List for Parker](https://www.parker.com/parkerimages/Parker.com/ParkerStore2014/Global%20Assets/PDFs/Product%20Info/4400_B10_Imperial%20Eastman%20to%20Parker.pdf) and not even have to get on the phone.